# reliably altering the $PATH with a script

Tags: shell, sh

I have a script that alters a few things for another program, one of those is to call said program with a set of different flags.

The flags are long, error prone, and difficult to remember, so this script I am writing wants to override that executable, so that when a user calls the script it is actually calling the script plus the extra complicated arguments.

I know of at least 3 ways to accomplish the above:

- Create an alias: `alias foo=/usr/bin/foo --compicated-flag ComplexArgument`
- Create a function:

  ```
  function foo {
      /usr/bin/foo --compicated-flag ComplexArgument
  }
  ```
- Alter the `$PATH` so that a non-standard location for a `foo` file gets called before the user's actual `foo` with these contents:

  ```
  /usr/bin/foo --compicated-flag ComplexArgument
  ```

My problem is that I want the user to be able to run a helper script that will set these with *just one command*. I don't want to prompt the user with a second action like "and now you need to source this file or export `$PATH`" every time.

Since the `ComplexArgument` is calculated programmatically and it changes a lot, neither the `alias` nor the `function` approach would work (e.g. declaring those in a `bashrc` or `zshrc`). It is also important to note that these changes should be temporary only, and a user might, or might not, want to set it. More reason why these changes should not be added to an RC shell file.

So the only item I keep falling back to is to altering the `$PATH`.

I know that to change an environment variable and affect a sub-shell I would need to call `exec`. Something like:

```
    export PATH=/path/to/other/foo:$PATH
    exec $SHELL
```

This way `$PATH` would "stick" to the sub-shell.

Except that, in certain environments, it most certainly does not.

For example in OSX, if you have HomeBrew installed, it is recommended that you alter the `$PATH` so that `/usr/local/bin` comes first so that the libraries that HomeBrew installs come first.

If a user defines it in his `.zshrc` like:

```
    PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

It means that regardless of what my script sets, ZSH will read the `.zshrc` file and get `/usr/local/bin` first.

If I use one of ZSH's flags to avoid reading a user's RC file, then other things will stop working, because the `$PATH` will no longer be set correctly and ZSH will *always* call `/etc/zshenv` which in some systems has this:

```
# system-wide environment settings for zsh(1)
if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi
```

Which makes it even worse since that *also* changes the `$PATH` to ensure some paths come before regardless of what `$PATH` was before.

So I find that two first items (`alias` and `function`) to not be adequate, and the third (to alter `$PATH`) to be non-reliable.

I know there has to be a proper way to do this, I understand the limitations of sub-shells and altering things on one script and make them persist, but is prompting the user to "source this file to alter `$PATH` or `export PATH=/path/to/foo:$PATH`" the only way to make this reliable?

Comment: Long and complicated arguments that change frequently?  Sounds like `ghostscript`.  Anyway, I would move `/usr/local/bin/whatever` to `/usr/local/bin/whatever.installed`, then write your own wrapper `/usr/local/bin/whatever` that does your work before `exec` the installed version.

Answer (score 0):

A fourth option would be a wrapper around the complicated function. So you would rename your complicated script from `complicated` to `complicated.orig` and then write a new `complicated` that calculates the arguments and then exec's `complicated.orig` with the newly calculated arguments. That way you are not reliant on the users all updating their login profiles to use your alias or function, and the path to the script will appear the same as it ever was to your users.

Answer (score 0):

Providing a helper script in the deployment of a software package is a very common technique. Think `service apache2 restart` that does exactly what you describe.